# how to store the data into NSMutableString?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hi all how to appends total data to NSMutableString what i am getting data from the

```
Webservices *details=[[Webservices alloc] init];
[details getMobileNumberDetails:phnotextfield.text];

NSLog(@"longitudes Arrays from %@",details.resultData);
```

> "-91.57696007",
>       "10.343234",
>       "74.982343",
>       "76.464844",
>       "76.464844",
>       "2.256",

so help me to store the data into NSMutableString by using for loop in iphone.

thanq for your replaying my another problem is i have to store all data from nsmutablestring into float values. according to your ans, when convert the nsmutablestring values into float as like

float datalist= [ myStr floatValue];  it showing 0.000 value. how to store the total result into float values  in iphone

Comment: what you want exactly ? you store all above number into a single string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
 NSString *XMLStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length]encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
 NSLog(@"the xml  product is %@",XMLStr);
```

Use this code i hope it helps You.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that tge array has NSNumber objects,

> ```
>     NSMutableString *myStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
>     for (NSNumber *temp in details.resultData) {
>         [myStr appendString:@"\""];
>         [myStr appendFormat:@"%f", temp.floatValue];
>         [myStr appendFormat:@"\","];
>     }
> ```